# xlsx подзаголовок

Tags: python, pandas, excel, форматирование

Пытаюсь сделать подзаголовок в таблице, пытаюсь добиться примерно такого результата
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'name': ['Manchester City', 'Real Madrid', 'Liverpool','FC Bayern München', 'FC Barcelona', 'Juventus'],
                                       'activity_type': ['English Premier League (1)', 'Spain Primera Division (1)','English Premier League (1)', 'German 1. Bundesliga (1)','Spain Primera Division (1)', 'Italian Serie A (1)'],
                                       'full_name_licensee': [176000000, 188500000, 90000000,100000000, 180500000, 105000000]})
df.to_excel("test.xlsx",index=False)
```

Вот таким образом у меня получилось сделать заголовки для каждой колонки, как я могу сделать главный заголовок который начинается с `1А` и заканчивается `1J`

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

Проще всего сначала записать DataFrame в Excel файл используя Pandas, а потом "допилить" всю "красоту" используя `openpyxl`:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.styles import Alignment

df.to_excel("tmp.xlsx", index=False)

wb = load_workbook("tmp.xlsx")
ws = wb.active

ws.insert_rows(0)
ws["A1"] = "LICENSE"
ws.merge_cells(start_row=1, start_column=1, end_row=1, end_column=10)
ws['A1'].alignment = Alignment(horizontal='center')

wb.save("result.xlsx")
wb.close()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]